# Fixed Position Relative to Parent Div with sliding sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like my sidebar to push the content across when opened which i have achived but my fixed navigation stays at the position of Left: 0px; relative to the veiwport rather than the relative positioned parent element. my nav's with is 100%

my sidebar works fine on firefox but breaks out of parent in chrome

[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVXRY/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar">

    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="nav">
            <p class="button"></p>    
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.content').toggleClass('slide');
        });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

MY CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    background: rgb(60,60,60);
    float:left;
    height: 600px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.content{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:600px;
    background: #FFF;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.slide{
    left: 250px;
}

#nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #0af;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #ddd;
}

 #nav p:before{
    content: "\e000";
}

.button{
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[VIEW HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVXRY/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `position: absolute;` to `.slide{...}`css will fix the problem in Chrome, you might also have to fix the animation when .slide class is removed

Good luck

[UPDATE]
HERE IS A WORKING EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/QdVKD/1/

FIXING THE WIDTH AND UNNEEDED SCROLL OF PAGE: http://jsfiddle.net/QdVKD/2/

Comment: Thanks! how would i fix the animation?

Comment: i can create the same effect by setting the nav's left value to inherit without having to change the animation but i want to be able to scroll across to see the rest of the page

Comment: Thats easy, by adding the same style for the nav, and slider
check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QdVKD/1/

Comment: Also I noticed that the animation causes the page to have a horizontal scroll, because you have the extra 250px on the left, so here is a fix for that :)
http://jsfiddle.net/QdVKD/2/